# Removing html tag from a string and adding a new line

Tags: c#, regex

I am using regex to remove html tags from my string

```html
Air Receiver <br /> Pressure Washer <br />Vehicle Lift<br />100T Crane Attachment<br />
```

which is working well.

```cs
ViewBag.PlantDetails =
    Regex.Replace(QuoteDetails.PlantDetails, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", " ").Trim();
```

which returns the following string -

```
Air Receiver Pressure Washer Vehicle Lift 100T Crane Attachment
```

My question is, is there a way to add a new line to the string so that it shows like below?

```html
Air Receiver
Pressure Washer
Vehicle Lift
100T Crane Attachment
```

Comment: Please don't try to parse HTML with regex. Use an HTML parser instead.

Comment: Your code at the top has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: _"is there a way to add a new line"_ - yes: Instead of replace by " " replace by [`Environment.NewLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline?view=net-6.0)

Comment: But to reiterate @gunr2171's point: Only do this if `<br />` will be the only tag you encounter here. If it's html, use html tools.

Comment: To add to @gunr2171 's comment, see [this very relevant post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/14868997)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if `<br />`, and exactly that (with the space and everything) is the only HTML tag that you'll encounter, then Regex is overkill. Use a simple string replace.

```
var input = "Air Receiver <br /> Pressure Washer <br />Vehicle Lift<br />100T Crane Attachment<br />";
var output = input.Replace("<br />", Environment.NewLine);
```

In your example, you have spaces *sometimes* on either end of the break, so trim it if you want.

```
output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, output.Split(Environment.NewLine).Select(x => x.Trim()));
```

If you really want to use Regex, it can be used to match the break and surrounding whitespace.

```
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s*<br \/>\s*", Environment.NewLine);
```